# Actionbar NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS ландшафтная ориентация

Tags: actionbar, android

Доброго  времени суток.
В ландшафтной ориентации, при большом количестве табов,табы преобразуются в выпадающий список, хотя при портретной все нормально. Как сделать табы в ландшафтной ориентации ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывайте `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` после добавления всех табов, а не до.